# How to change colors of inline svg packaged with webpack?

Tags: css, svg, webpack

I've tried a variety of things and it always comes out black.

I've got this svg:

```
<!-- Generated by IcoMoon.io -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <title>power-cord</title>
  <path d="M32 8.828l-2.828-2.828-5.586 5.586-3.172-3.172 5.586-5.586-2.828-2.828-5.586 5.586-3.586-3.586-2.707 2.707 16 16 2.707-2.707-3.586-3.586 5.586-5.586z"></path>
  <path d="M24.814 21.056l-13.87-13.87c-2.994 3.591-6.391 9.139-4.044 13.913l-4.133 4.133c-0.972 0.972-0.972 2.563 0 3.535l0.464 0.464c0.972 0.972 2.563 0.972 3.536 0l4.133-4.133c4.774 2.348 10.322-1.049 13.913-4.043z"></path>
</svg>
```

Webpack/Quasar/Vue is packaging and delivering it into this image tag:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" class="profile">
```

Cool!

Now I should be able to color it using `fill`?  In Chrome devtools, I see the fill attributes applied (through CSS and fiddling with it)

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" class="profile" style="
    fill: purple;
    color: purple;
">
```

But the little guy always shows up black :-(

Editing and repackaging svg with `fill="purple"` works.
With `fill="var(--q-color-primary)"` doesn't use CSS variables.

```
<!-- Generated by IcoMoon.io -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <title>power-cord</title>
  <path fill="var(--q-color-primary)" d="M32 8.828l-2.828-2.828-5.586 5.586-3.172-3.172 5.586-5.586-2.828-2.828-5.586 5.586-3.586-3.586-2.707 2.707 16 16 2.707-2.707-3.586-3.586 5.586-5.586z"></path>
  <path fill="purple" d="M24.814 21.056l-13.87-13.87c-2.994 3.591-6.391 9.139-4.044 13.913l-4.133 4.133c-0.972 0.972-0.972 2.563 0 3.535l0.464 0.464c0.972 0.972 2.563 0.972 3.536 0l4.133-4.133c4.774 2.348 10.322-1.049 13.913-4.043z"></path>
</svg>
```

I'll have 100's of these images, that need to be colored in different themes and would love a simple asset pipeline.

What's the simplest way to change these image colors dynamically after they've been packaged?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you want.

Images that are loaded via a Data URL are treated as if they are an image file on a different file system.  Once they are decoded and rendered they are effectively a bitmap image - the same as if they were a PNG.

Your options are:

- Inline the SVG in your HTML
- Use an `<object>` to embed the SVG and alter the styles with JS
- Use JS code that replaces your `<img>` tags with injected SVG fron the associated file.
- Have multiple versions of the SVG with different colors (either as separate SVGs or by using an SVG sprite sheet).

Re: inline svg vs. icon fonts, [this article](https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/) sums it up nicely:  "If you can go IE 9+ / Android 3+, inline SVG is better at pretty much everything than icon fonts."

Comment: Ok,snap.   Is there any reason to prefer an icon font (e.g. icomoon.io) to inline svg?  I want to support IE11+ and mobile for a PWA.

Comment: That's kind of a matter of opinion I guess. But I think consensus is moving towards SVGs now. This article may help: https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/

Comment: Awesome!  Great article w/ thorough review.  TL;DR: " If you can go IE 9+ / Android 3+, inline SVG is better at pretty much everything than icon fonts."

Comment: well @PaulLeBeau, wouldn't there be a possibility to write a custom loader that theoretically could transform the asset before the 'asset/inline' is generated, I'm thinking from SCSS/CSS etc. (not from template) for a css rule `background-image: url(../Icons/magnifier.svg?fill=f0f&color=0f0);`, a loader could probably pre-process it. This would come in very handy. I'm inlining svg:s without the querystring right now, this would be a nice addition to my current workflow.

Comment: @JonasCarlbaum Yes. You could write a preprocssor. Or you could replace the background image at runtime via JS.  There are already example code for the latter option - at leasnt for `<img>` anyway. Not sure about `background-image`.